# Error in Relationship whit entities in doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I have an error in my relationship between entities. When I create DB with my entities there's no error, but if I try find one element's relationship the error is returned:

> Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\DefaultQuoteStrategy::getJoinColumnName() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php on line 1670 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\DefaultQuoteStrategy.php on line 66.

My relationships are:

Role.php

```
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Model\User", inversedBy="idRole")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="UserRole")
 */     
protected $idUser;
```

User.php

```
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Login\Model\Role", mappedBy="idUser")
 */
protected $idRole;
```

I have tried other methods listed in [documentation of doctrine ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-manytomany), but I am getting the same error.

How I correct this problem?

Comment: Did you preset those properties with an ArrayCollection object in the entity constructor?

Comment: Yes, in the end of my entity constructor i have $this->idUser = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection(); and the same in User.php being idRole getting new ArrayCollection().

Comment: Then I need the full entities to be able to check where the problem might be.